# Strange error with in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I have a strange issue with the in-app purchase in one of my apps. Some months ago it worked perfectly...

When I try to make a purchase with my own, real phone (android 2.3.5) in my app, Google Play opens, and then show a message box "You already own this item". I checked in my Google checkout account, and I didn't buy it before (in fact I did for my tests some months ago, but I always canceled the orders).

Two buttons on this message box :

- OK: I go back to my app
- Details: well... it just makes Google Play crash !

This messagebox is shown by Google Play, not by my app. has anyone already met this issue ?
I checked some other apps with in-app purchase, they work. And I still get orders for my in-app purchase, so seems it's happening only for me ...

I am using Robomedia AndroidBillingLibrary : https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary

Thanks for help.

Comment: I've started seeing the same issue. Did a refund then tried to re-purchase for testing purposes. First, it opened a window with the 'Accept & Buy', but the button did not react to presses. Restarted device, and have been getting the 'you already own this' message since then. 'clear data' trick didn't work. Google searches show several similar reports, all dated 1 or 2 days ago (Aug 28/29). Maybe something is up with the play app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been an issue on Google's side and they must have solved it, because it works now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Perhaps it takes awhile to update.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by going to the App Info for 'Google Play' and clearing the cache and clearing the data.  It appears that GP caches purchase information on the device and rarely if ever checks to see if purchases have been refunded.  I would recommend al